# Set focus to another element with default button event?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have tried the following:

```
<Button IsDefault="True" Content="Process Test File" 
        FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=txtClientId}" 
        Command="{Binding ProcessFileCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</Button>
```

I have the button set to default. So, when the user hits the enter key it processes the command, but doesn't set the focus like asked. However, when clicked with the mouse it does set the focus. I'm sure there's got to be an easy way to get the setting focus to work with the default action too.

Comment: Usually, `FocusManager.FocusedElement` only gets "triggered" when the controls are loaded... The fact that it is also doing something when the Button is clicked is puzzling, but I certainly wouldn't expect it to work in any other case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the focusing in the Button's `Click` event. It'll get called when you press Enter, too.

```
<Button IsDefault="True" Content="Process Test File" 
        Command="{Binding ProcessFileCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        Click="Button_Click">
</Button>
```

Then, in code-behind:

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Keyboard.Focus(txtClientId);
}
```

Comment: I was hoping there was a way around it. I guess this wouldn't exactly break MVVM since I'm not using the code behind for any VM or data.

Comment: It wouldn't break MVVM, indeed, and the only no-code-behind solution I can think of involves creating a behavior with an attached property and all that... Which feels a bit like an overkill for this (but if you're interested on that, we could look into it)